# Is there a way to filter desc output?

Tags: sql, oracle

I ran desc on a table and got 60+ results and don't really want to read through them all to find what I'm looking for when I know part of the key already, given that I'm going to have to do this repeatedly.

What I'd like to be able to do is something like this~

```
desc <tablename> where column like '%someText%';
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: no you can't do that..use something like `select * from user_tab_columns where table_name=<tablename> and column_name like '%someText%'`

Comment: you could also add `ORDER BY column_name DESC`

Comment: What do you mean by "got 60+ results"? `desc <tablename>` returns a single result. Do you mean, you found out that the table has 60+ columns? Then what vkp wrote is the way to go; or perhaps `all_tab_columns` if the table is not yours, but it is visible to you. (And perhaps also select specific columns from the catalog instead of `*`.)

Comment: Yes, the table has 60+ columns. Unfortunately vkp's suggestion gave me an empty table as a result. I am new to SQL and new to this job, I am not sure how to investigate why this trick did not work. Certainly the user_tab_columns table is quite large, `select * from user_tab_columns;` takes 30+ seconds to run.

Comment: vkp did not say `select * from user_tab_columns` - of course that takes a long time. vkp had a `where` clause. The query did not return anything... perhaps the table is in another schema? That is why I suggested `all_tab_columns` instead. Start with a small table and a column you are sure exists, so you can see how all of this works. It will serve you well in the future.

Comment: It was because I used `user_tab_columns` and it's a table I'm not the owner of. With `all_tab_columns` it worked as desired. Thanks

Comment: Oracle is (usually) CASE SENSITIVE. so you should (normally) use UPPERCASE for the table_name `select * from user_tab_columns where table_name='MYTABLE' order by column_name DESC`

Comment: I would say we can :-) but it's not pretty.

Let me just state - DESC(RIBE) **does NOT do that**, but there might be a workaround, like so:

    $ echo 'desc table_name' >> /tmp/desc_table_name.txt
    $ sqlplus user/pass
    SQL> !sqlplus user/pass @/tmp/desc_table_name.txt | grep -i ***someText *** . Unfortunately I can't test it now, as I don't have a ssh connection available at the moment to try it out.